# Loading an image into imageview via code won't load unless I previously give an image to the imageview via xml

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Hi I have a regular imageview width 600dp height 600dp, no scale. When I take a photo with my camera and try to load into the imageview it won't load it, nothing appears, no errors are thrown, however when I give any image to the imageview inside the xml, then glide does load the image that I take with the camera or select from memory, I also tried Android code and the same, will load only when setting an image to the imageview via xml, is this a known behavior?

Comment: Some code would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Actually nothing wrong with it. If image size is much bigger than it will take time to set on imageview. so you should use placeholder method of glide. So user wait for image to loaded on imageview